# Hibernate - Recursive query to get object by level

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, criteria

I have a question about Hibernate recursive GET. I have a Class:

```
public class Person {
    private int PersonId;
    private Set<Person> relations = new HashSet<Person>(0);
```

Friends of level x of a person A is defined as below: 
- if x = 1, friends of level x of A are all person which have direct relation with A
- if x > 1, friends of level x of A are all friends of friend of level (x-1) of A.

Exemple: 
- A have 3 friend A1, A2, A3
- A1 have 2 friends A1.1 and A1.2
- A2 have 1 friends A2.1
- A3 doesn't have any friend except A
--> A1.1, A1.2 and A2.1 are friends of level 2 of A

The question is: use HQL or SQL or Criteria to find all relation of level x of A.

Thanks for any suggestion :-)

Comment: Switch to [neo4j](http://neo4j.com/) - it's easy there! ;)

Comment: Hi isnot2bad, could you explain more clearly? Thanks

Comment: Neo4j is a graph-database that is optimized for graph-like structures and queries. Its built-in cypher query language would exactly fit your needs. But as Neo4j is a separate database, it might not be an option to you.